# How to style custom HR element in CSS?

Tags: css

Does anyone know how you could style something like this in CSS using the `<hr` element?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `<hr>` uses `border`, so, override its border values

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `:after` `:before` pseudo elements.

```css
hr {
  border: none;
}

hr:after, 
hr:before{
  display: block;
  content:'';
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
}
hr:after{
  width: 20%;
}

hr:before{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Comment: I went with this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2 borders:

```css
hr {
  color:red;
  border-top:10px solid;
  border-left:100px solid;
  height:10px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: On my computer (ubuntu/chrome) i see an artefact around the <hr>

Answer (score 0):

Change width for part class as you need, the same about border

```css
.full{
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}

.part{
  height: 0;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr class="full" />
<hr class="part" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style the `<hr>` and use a pseudo class for the bottom part.

```css
hr {
  border: 10px red solid;
}

hr::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```